# Prove $\int\limits_1^\infty f(x) \, dx<\infty\implies\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f(i)<\infty$

Tags: calculus

> Theorem: Let $f$ be a positive function, continuous  and decreasing in an interval $[1,\infty]$. If
>
> $$\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty$$
>
> therefore we have:
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)<\infty$$
>
> and reciprocally.

By the definition of $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x)\,\Delta x$

As the $\lim_{\Delta x}\Delta x=dx$ is constantly infinitesimally small, we conclude that if $\int\limits_1^\infty f(x) \, dx<\infty$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty f(i)<\infty$ is true.

**Questions**:

Do you think this prove is right? Can I treat $\lim_{\Delta x}\Delta x$ as constant?

Comment: Have you studied partitions?

Comment: @RabMakh       Yes I have.

Comment: is $f$ increasing or decreasing ?

Comment: @Ahmad Please check out the update! Decreasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_i^{i+1} f(x)\,dx \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_i^{i+1} f(i)\, dx = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) <\infty. \\
& \text{This instance of “$\le$'' is true because $f$ is decreasing.} \\[20pt]
& \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) \le \sum_{i=2}^\infty f(i) = \sum_{i=2}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i f(i)\,dx \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{i-1}^i f(x)\,dx = \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx < \infty. \\
& \text{The second “$\le$'' on this line is true because $f$ is decreasing.}
\end{align}

Comment: How can $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) \le \sum_{i=2}^\infty f(i) $ be true if $f(x)$ is decreasing and you start summing from 2?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=\left[1<2<3<\dots<n\right]$, since $f$ is decreasing on $[1,\infty]$ then we can say that$$\max_{x \in [n, n+1]}f(x)=f(n)$$
$$\min_{x \in [n, n+1]}f(x)=f(n+1)$$

We also know that $L(P,f) \le \int_1^n f(t)\,dt \le U(P,f)$

$$L(P,f)=\sum_{k=2}^n f(a_k) \le \int_1^n f(t)\,dt \le \sum_{k=1}^n f(a_k)=U(P,f)$$

You can continue the argument by taking $n \to \infty$ and arguing that if $\int \mathbb{or} \sum$ converges then it is bounded.